# Button in asp.net web forms dont fire event

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, event-handling

can you help me with something i struggle for 4 days, button event doesn't  fire :( In the MasterPage i use this to add control

```
 <Login:UserLogin runat="server" ID="UserLogin"  EnableViewState="false" > </Login:UserLogin>
```

and the control is this

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UserLogin.ascx.cs" Inherits="BookApartmentsPortal.controls.UserLogin"  %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="MultiLanguage" Namespace="MultiLanguage.multilanguage" %>

<%--
<script type="text/javascript">        
       function DeleteKartItems() {  
                var inputEmail =   $("#ctl00_UserLogin_txtEmailVal").val();
                var user = {
                    email: "s.krastanov",
                    password: "1"
                };


              $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'PublicDefault.aspx/Getvalues',
               data: JSON.stringify({ person: user }),
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (msg) {
                   $("#divResult").html("success");
               },
               error: function (e) {
                   $("#divResult").html("Something Wrong.");
               }
           });
           $("#ctl00_PublicDefault_buttonLog").Click();
   }
</script>--%>


    <h3>
        <MultiLanguage:MultiLanguageLiteral ID="MultiLanguageLiteral13" runat="server" Resource="669" />
    </h3>
    <form action="/" method="POST" id="formasd">
        <div class="">
            <MultiLanguage:MultiLanguageLiteral ID="MultiLanguageLiteral14" runat="server" Resource="858" />
            <%--user name input field--%>
            <input type="text"  class="modal-input" runat="server" size="20" id="txtEmailVal"
                name="txtEmail" />
            <%--  <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="modal-input" ID="txtEmailVal" ></asp:TextBox> --%>
            <MultiLanguage:MultiLanguageLiteral ID="MultiLanguageLiteral21" runat="server" Resource="205" />
            <%--password input field--%>
            <%--<input type="password" class="modal-input" runat="server" size="1" maxlength="20" id="txtPassword" />--%>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="modal-input" TextMode="Password" ID="txtPassword"
                MaxLength="20" CausesValidation="false"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">
            </asp:Label>

    <asp:Panel ID="panelLogin" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLogon">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogon" Text="Click" CssClass="login-btn" OnClick="btnLogon_Click"></asp:Button>
            </asp:Panel>
      <%--      <button class="login-btn" runat="server" id="btnLogon" name="btnLogon" onclick="DeleteKartItems()">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
                <MultiLanguage:MultiLanguageLiteral ID="MultiLanguageLiteral4" runat="server" Resource="1270" />
            </button>--%>

            <div id="divResult">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="LoginFB" Target="_blank" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook fb-login">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
        <MultiLanguage:MultiLanguageLiteral ID="MultiLanguageLiteral27" runat="server" Resource="1306" /></asp:HyperLink>
    <a href="#lost-pass" class="button-modal various-login"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
        <MultiLanguage:MultiLanguageLiteral ID="MultiLanguageLiteral22" runat="server" Resource="164" /></a>
    <a href="#reg" class="button-modal reg"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <MultiLanguage:MultiLanguageLiteral ID="MultiLanguageLiteral23" runat="server" Resource="1271" /></a>
```

Backend is this:

```
    public partial class UserLogin : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {



          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (IsPostBack) 
            {

                this.btnLogon.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnLogon_Click);
                Response.Write("you click");
            }

            this.btnLogon.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnLogon_Click);

            LoginFB.NavigateUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth/?client_id=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"] + "&redirect_uri=http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"].ToString() + "/Publish/UserFB.aspx&response_type=code&state=1";

        }

        override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            //btnLogon.ServerClick += new EventHandler(btnLogon_Click);
            this.btnLogon.Click += new System.EventHandler(btnLogon_Click);
            //btnLogon.ServerClick += new CommandEventHandler(btnLogonClick);
           // btnLogon.Command += btnLogon_Click;
        }


        public void btnLogon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = "submit button is press";
           // if (LoginSet == false )
           // {
                string Name = txtPassword.Text;
                string Dev = txtEmailVal.Value;

                String[] RemoteAddr = Request.ServerVariables.GetValues("REMOTE_ADDR");
                if (RemoteAddr.Length <= 0)
                    return;

                LoginDB oLoginDb = new LoginDB(txtEmailVal.Value.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim(), true, RemoteAddr[0].ToString());
                oLoginDb.Database = new SQLDatabase(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnectionString"].ToString()));

                try
                {
                    if (oLoginDb.Authenticate(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecKeyIni"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecKeySec"].ToString()))
                    {
                        Response.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Expires = DateTime.Now;
                        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtEmailVal.Value.Trim(), false);

                        Session["LoginUserName"] = txtEmailVal.Value.Trim();
                     //   _loginSet = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                     //   _loginSet = false;

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception Exception)
                {
                    Context.Trace.Warn(Exception.Message);
                    Global.ErrorMessage(Exception.Message, Context);
                 //   _loginSet = false;

                }

            //}
        }
}
```

This control is for login form and i just cant get the values from input boxes because event don't trigger. One idea was to make AJAX post to static method but after that i cant make new session with this variables.
I try everything and this button just doesn't fire the event. I don't know what to do next, can you help me.

Comment: Is it executed without errors? I alwasy get " of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server." because of missing runat attribute in your example

Comment: Which button is the problem?

Comment: if i put runat="server" on the form from the control (
    <form action="/" method="POST" id="formasd" runat="server">)  browser doesn't render anything

Comment: the problem is:   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogon" Text="Click" CssClass="login-btn" OnClick="btnLogon_Click"></asp:Button>

Answer (score 0):

Ok after one more day of struggle, i manage to make a little walk around path: 
In the first step i made a Button to fire event (javascript function) and make cookie, after that i make click event for actual asp:Button :

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
       function LoginClicked() {  
                var inputEmail =   $("#txtEmail").val();
                var inputPass =   $("#txtPassword").val();
                if(inputEmail != "" && inputPass != ""){

                var userSet = inputEmail + "&" + inputPass;
                setCookie("UserSettings", userSet, 1);

                function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
                    var d = new Date();
                    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*1*60*1000));
                    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
                    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
                 }
          $("#ctl00_UserLogin_btnLogon").click();
           }
   }
</script>
```

And here is the buttons:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panekl">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogon" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CssClass="no-display" ></asp:Button>
      </asp:Panel>
             <button class="login-btn" id="btnLogon1" name="btnLogon1" onclick="LoginClicked()">
             <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i><MultiLanguage:MultiLanguageLiteral ID="MultiLanguageLiteral4" runat="server" Resource="1270" />
```

And in the back end, i get the cookie, split it, and check for validation:

```
public void btnLogon_Click()
        {

           if (LoginSet == false )
           {
                string[] txtSome = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"].Value.Split('&');
                if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null && txtEmailVal != "" && txtPassword != "")
                {
                    txtEmailVal = txtSome[0].Trim();
                    txtPassword = txtSome[1].Trim();

                }

                String[] RemoteAddr = Request.ServerVariables.GetValues("REMOTE_ADDR");
                if (RemoteAddr.Length <= 0)
                    return;

                LoginDB oLoginDb = new LoginDB(txtEmailVal, txtPassword, true, RemoteAddr[0].ToString());
                oLoginDb.Database = new SQLDatabase(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnectionString"].ToString()));

                try
                {
                    if (oLoginDb.Authenticate(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecKeyIni"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecKeySec"].ToString()))
                    {

                        Session["IdUserLogin"] = txtEmailVal;

                       _loginSet = true;
                       HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
                       myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                       Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
                       Label1.Text = "submit button is press";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                       _loginSet = false;

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception Exception)
                {
                    Context.Trace.Warn(Exception.Message);
                    Global.ErrorMessage(Exception.Message, Context);
                 _loginSet = false;

                }

           }
        }
```

This was the only way i figured out to get values from the control.